# self.view.frame.height = 460 in iPhone5

Tags: ios, view, height, frame, iphone-5

I'm updating my app for the 4-inch screen of iPhone5.

However, I found that, only in my root view (the view of my rootViewController, a navigation controller) the value of self.view.frame.height is 548 (showing status bar), which is what I want.

Once I push any viewController in the navigation stack, the value of self.view.frame.height in  the pushed viewController becomes 460, it seems that the viewController does not know it is running on iPhone5.

To be clear, I hardly use xib files. In fact I just created void xib files,, like showed in the picture below. All the buttons, tables and other subViews are added manually in viewDidLoad method of each viewController.

[image: My empty nib files]

I've added the default-568h@2x.png to the project to adjust iPhone5, but I have not done any other change to the settings to my project or xib files.

The value of 460 of self.view.frame.height would incorrectly affect the positions of some subViews in the view of a viewController on 4-inch screen, but I have not found way to make it realize that the value should actually be 548.

How should I do? Is there any step I missed in adjusting 4-inch screen? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Select the drop down box "Size" in the "Simulated Metrics" Tab.

[image: Size Dropdown]

Then change the selection to "Retina 4 Full Screen" and your done.

Comment: But my app also needs to support 3.5-inch screens, if I change it to "Retina 4 Full Screen", what would happen when it is running on 3.5-inch screen devices?

Comment: You need to add separate xib files to support separate devices.

Comment: An example of this can be seen in the AppDelegate.m file, near line 38.

Comment: thanks for your information, but which AppDelegate.m file do you refer to?

Comment: You should be able to find it with your other class files. What kind of project did you create from the start? it should be there automatically if you used any project templates in the IOS/Applications tab.

Comment: Search the file tree of your application folder to try and find it, if it is not showing up in the project file explorer.